# Regular expression for positive numbers from 1-99 up to 2 decimal places

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression for accepting positive numbers from 1-99 and accepting decimals up to 2 places
I have written this expression

```
([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])(.[0-9]{1,2})?
```

But when I tested the expression, it accepted 100 and decimals up to 3 places, while I wanted decimals only up to 2 places and 100 should not be accepted.

Comment: Did someone edit to add the backslash to the RE - it wasn't there before, was it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

As David said, you need to escape your `.`, or it matches any character, including a digit.

Answer (score 3):

Escape the `.` which matches any character as `\.`. You have no delimiters around this, so note that this would match, for example, 91.23 in the string 191.234.

```
([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])(\.[0-9]{1,2})?
```

Comment: Just for clarity, "delimiters" in this case are also known as "anchors".

Comment: Does asker want to require the decimals?  I read it as allowing them, so I'd make the second group optional...

Answer (score -1):

I would go with this `^(?:\d[1-9]|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])(?:\.(?:[0-9][1-9]|[1-9]))?$`

```
0 FAIL
0.0 FAIL
0.00 FAIL
0.1 FAIL
0.12 FAIL
1 PASS
12 PASS
135 FAIL
1.00 FAIL?
01.35 PASS
10.35 PASS
12.01 PASS
12.1 PASS
12.23 PASS
12.234 FAIL
```

EDIT ANSWER AFTER FIRST COMMENT.

Comment: @DavidM I edited the answer, I misunderstood you didn't want to catch 0.

Comment: IF you want to handle 1.00 for some reason use this instead **^(?:\d[1-9]|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])(?:\.\d\d)?$**

Answer (score -1):

This will match 1-99 and up to 2 decimal places.

```
((0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.[0-9]{1,2})
```